# Increase master timeout for create index elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting timeout exceptions like below during index creation.

```
Exception: System.Exception: Error creating index '[metadata]-[content].[292]-[]-[1]': Status: 503, Type: process_cluster_event_timeout_exception, Error: Type: process_cluster_event_timeout_exception Reason: "failed to process cluster event (create-index [[metadata]-[content].[292]-[]-[1]], cause [api]) within 30s"
```

I need to know if increasing master timeout will help? if so how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create your index using `PUT my_index?master_timeout=60s`

Its default is set to 30s

I hope this query parameter is relevant for your version.

[From Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/cluster-update-settings.html)

Comment: I dont see this in elasticsearch.yml, should i add this?

Comment: Yes you should add it to override the default. but i'm not sure that's the way to solve this issue (by increasing timeout). maybe you should increase your heap size of number of threads per node.

Comment: 2019-11-25 15:54:11 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Exception in thread "main" ception: unknown setting [cluster.publish.timeout] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings

Comment: What is your version?

Comment: version is 5.6.8

Comment: thanks, but im quite new to elastic search. not sure of index name. how to get that?

Comment: You got the above error while trying to create an index. just add master_timeout=60s as query param.